# Theorem prover for biology: Isabelle/HOL/Coq/Mizar etc. or SNARK or HyLL?

Tags: ide, scientific-computing

I would like to know which theorem prover would best fit the needs of biologists especially being able to tackle biological 'types' and operations/functions.

I know [HyLL](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Joelle.Despeyroux/papers/fmmb14.pdf) will do it great and [SNARK](http://www.ai.sri.com/snark/tutorial/tutorial.html) too will achieve it. But I would like to know if there is any better specialized and customized software for biological theorem proving specially which could be dealing with characteristic biological objects and operations- populations, individuals, phylogenies and mating, molecular or ecological interactions like activation/inhibition or parasitism, commensalism etc.

Is there a popular or better software that is used/can be used to handle exclusively biological and pure biological objects and operations and rest of the things biological i.e. such theories could be axiomatized or constructed and developed within it.

I have been thinking about Isabelle as it is my favourite, but just before I jump deep into it, I want to have advice about any other options.

Comment: I learnt that Computer Science forum is a better place for automated theorem proving querries; can someone please move this question there..?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/39508/2462, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70669/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/42397683/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  If you post it on the wrong site, you can delete the question and post it elsewhere, or flag it for moderator attention to ask moderators to migrate it, but please don't post in multiple places.